# Парсер изменения цены товара с Озона для отправки уведомления в Телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, парсер, telegram

Пытаюсь сделать парсер цены на определенный нужный мне товар, чтобы при снижении цены мне приходило уведомление в ТГ боте.

Файл Main.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from telegram import Bot
import time

# Загрузка настроек из config.py
from config import TOKEN, CHAT_ID, PRODUCT_URL

# Функция для получения цены товара
def get_product_price(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        price_tag = soup.find('span', {'class': 'b9r'})
        price = float(price_tag.text.replace(' ', '').replace('₽', '').replace(',', '.'))
        return price
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка при получении цены: {e}")
        return None

# Основная функция для мониторинга цены и отправки уведомления
def check_price():
    previous_price = None
    
    while True:
        current_price = get_product_price(PRODUCT_URL)
        
        if current_price is not None:
            if previous_price is not None and current_price < previous_price:
                message = f"Цена упала! Текущая цена: {current_price} ₽"
                bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
                bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=message)
            
            previous_price = current_price
        
        time.sleep(3600)  # Проверять цену каждый час

# Запуск функции мониторинга цены
check_price()
```

Вылазит ошибка `403 Client Error: Forbidden` и как её исправить я не знаю.
Ссылка на товар https://www.ozon.ru/product/kostyum-takticheskiy-muzhskoy-demisezonnyy-turisticheskiy-na-flise-huntsman-gorka-5-rybolovnyy-836148527

Файл Config.py

```
TOKEN = 'token' # номер токена
CHAT_ID = 'chat_id'  #  ID чата в Telegram
PRODUCT_URL = 'https://www.ozon.ru/product/kostyum-takticheskiy-muzhskoy-demisezonnyy-turisticheskiy-na-flise-huntsman-gorka-5-rybolovnyy-836148527'  # Ссылка на товар
MONITOR_INTERVAL = 3600  # Интервал мониторинга в секундах (1 час)
```

Вопрос - как это реализовать, чтобы работало корректно?

Comment: Посмотрите, чем отличается ваш запрос по указанному url с тем, что по факту делает браузер. Судя по всему каким-то образом сайт понимает, что вы - машина и выдает 403. Лучший вариант понять, что к чему - скопировать запрос как curl, выполнить его. Потом конвертировать через curl2python и попытаться выполнить запрос через код. Дальше действовать исходя из этого

Comment: @Ivan, в Network слишком много файлов и я не понимаю, куда мне смотреть и что делать. Не могли бы Вы подсказать на примере приведенной выше страницы?

Comment: вам нужен самый первый по waterfall'у запрос во вкладке network

Comment: @Ivan я скопировал как curl, конвертировал его в Интернете и получил порядка 4 тысяч строчек кода. Что мне с ним делать теперь? Или я что-то не то делаю?

Comment: Вот. Посмотрите, чем запрос, который вы отправляете выше отличается от того, что вы отправили путем curl, и добавьте нужную разницу в ваш код

Comment: @Ivan Я, видимо, чего-то не понимаю. У меня в коде UserAgent это одна-две строчки, там - порядка 4 тысяч. Что мне с чем сравнивать?

Comment: Еще раз. Ваш запрос в коде, который вы делаете, имеет в себе одни данные (свои куки, заголовки, может быть тело, еще что-то). Тот запрос, который фактически делает браузер - он другой. Нужно понять, что такого делает браузер, что не делаете вы в своем коде при составлении запроса, что сайт пропускает браузер, но не вас. Может быть там сначала открывается какой-то js и выполняется, а потом происходит редирект на страницу, или может быть еще что-то. Это и нужно выяснить. Самый простой, на мой взгляд способ - сравнить запрос браузера и ваш путем сравнения curl-команды и вашего кода